# How to install jupyter labextension?

Tags: python, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am trying to install **jupyter labextenstion** using instruction given in https://github.com/Liorba/jupyterlab-spark-ui-tab

```
An error occured.
ValueError: This extension does not yet support the current version of JupyterLab.


Conflicting Dependencies:
JupyterLab              Extension              Package
>=2.0.0-alpha.3 <2.1.0  >=0.19.1 <0.20.0       @jupyterlab/application
>=2.0.0-alpha.3 <2.1.0  >=0.19.1 <0.20.0       @jupyterlab/apputils
```

I have tried with a different version of **jupyterlab** still facing this issue.

If anyone solved same kind of problem please suggest a solution.

Comment: Please check here ... https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_install.html

Comment: @BloodyProgrammer, Facing the same issue.